# Deleting min value from table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, min

I have a table of 10 high scores, when a new user comes along with a new high score that's greater than the lowest, I want to delete the minimum score from the table. I have tried every suggested way of doing this. Please can someone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work. You'd run it after inserting the new record.

```
delete from t t1 where t1.score not in 
(select t2.score from t t2 order by t2.score desc limit 10)
```

If you have a unique ID for each record in the table, then I'd modify it as follows:

```
delete from t t1 where t1.id not in 
(select t2.id from t t2 order by t2.score desc limit 10)
```

Comment: I only have the one table in this case so how would it work with the t2?

Comment: @LukeVarty t1 and t2 are just aliases for the same table (the table named t in this example). What's happening here is you are creating a subquery against the same table you're doing a delete on, and deleting based on those results.

Comment: @LukeVarty don't forget to choose an answer to your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete from the table -- way too much maintenance involved.  Just run the query:

```
select t.*
from t
order by t.score desc
limit 10;
```

You can put an index on `(score)`, so this runs faster.

You can encapsulate this in a view.

Comment: Wouldn't this become inefficient?

Comment: This doesn't delete the lowest scores from the table; it only selects the top 10 scores, which doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @LukeVarty . . . Probably not, especially if you have an index.